# Difference between "Selfish" and "Self Centered"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I have mostly seen the word "**Selfish**" used in depicting negative attribute of a person, like:-

- Don't put Rogers in the Team, he is way too *selfish* to be of any good for the team!!

And I have also used the term "**Self Centered**" having sort of similar meaning, but used in a much lighter sense.

So what exactly is the difference between the two? And when should be one used over the other?

Comment: Here, did you take a look at this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43645/difference-between-selfish-and-self-centered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define selfish

> (of a person, action, or motive) lacking consideration for other people; concerned chiefly with one's own personal profit or pleasure.

define self-centered

> preoccupied with oneself and one's affairs.

Self-centered is used in a lighter sense because it means that you are in your own world, while not necessarily harming others. Selfish means that you look for your own benefit, even if it does harm others.